# local description of $\mathbb{P}^2$-fibrations over $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, fibration, minimal-model-program

Let $X$ be a rational threefold (over the field of complex numbers) with terminal singularities. It is well-known that $X$ has only finitely many singular points $x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_n$.
To be more precise, I am especially interested in the case where there is a Mori fibration $\phi: X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ with general fiber isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$. Then over $\mathbb{P}^1 \setminus \{ \phi(x_1),\ldots, \phi(x_n)\}$ this Mori fibration is simply a $\mathbb{P}^2$-bundle.

Question: Is there an explicit description of $X$ locally around $x_i$? Here by explicit I have in mind for instance a local description by equations or as a quotient group. At least I would like a description which enables me to blow-up and blow-down and understand what I get, and also to have an idea on how degenerate the singular fibers can be.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509529.

Comment: @Sasha Nice reference, but only the case where the degenerating surface has quotient singularity is treated. Is there a way in general to have some kind of "canonical" birational map to a P^2 bundle? Or at least to something with mild singularities? (when I mean canonical, I mean something that would be equivariant why any group action).

Comment: @JérémyBlanc: Let $D \subset X$ be a class of a relative hyperplane section for $\phi$ (I think it is well defined as a Weil divisor) and take $F = \phi_*O_X(D)$. I guess $F$ is a torsion free sheaf on $P^1$, hence a vector bundle. Its rank is three and there is a birational map $X \dashrightarrow P_{P^1}(F^\vee)$. I guess it is canonical.

Comment: @Sasha: I am a bit puzzled by your comment. Firstly there are many hyperplane sections, not necessarily equivalent, so which one do you take? Secondly, it seems to me that pushing forward of Weil divisors does not work, so one has to take Cartier divisors, like multiples of the canonical divisors, but when the multiple is big, I do not see how to do.

Comment: @JérémyBlanc: I think you can take any hyperplane class. Also I do not suggest to push forward the divisor --- instead I suggest to push forward its associated torsion free sheaf (the dual sheaf of the ideal of this divisor).